# Add new record to ODBC linked table in Access using VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I am trying to add new records to a ODBC linked table in VBA Access. When the table was local, stored within the Access database, there was no issue. But when I uploaded the table to our Azure SQL server and linked it to the Access database the code no longer works. The code is on the "onclick" event of a button.

The code is used to add a quick record of when a user logs in to the Access application. I've linked the other server tables for forms and reports of the database, no problems. But have never had to add records in VBA before. The reason it needs to be done in VBA is because it needs to be hidden from the user.

```
   Dim Rst As Recordset

         Set Rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblLoginLog", dbOpenDynaset)
            With Rst
                .AddNew
                !User = ID
                !LoginDate = Now()
                .Update
            End With
```

tblLoginLog is the name of the table,
User is a number field for the employee number,
LoginDate is a date field for when login is successful.

If the table is stored locally in the database, the code works, but when the table is moved to the server nothing happens. When I click on the button, literally nothing happens. No error messages, nothing, and when I open the table, no data has been passed to the table.

Comment: Does this help https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4af80203-8dd7-4d67-9ffe-f51b5c28b46d/cant-update-some-sql-azure-linked-tables-from-access

Comment: You have to add `dbSeeChanges` option in call `Set Rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblLoginLog", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)`. And check if there Primary Key defined for "tblLoginLog" table.

Comment: @4dmonster I think that works - let me test further and I'll let you know. Thanks in advance

Comment: @4dmonster Have been using the additional code you suggested for the last couple of days and it now works a treat. In case anyone has this issue in the future - `Set Rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblLoginLog", dbOpenDynaset)`  works for local tables, `Set Rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblLoginLog", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)` works for server tables